# How to search for shadow-root selector in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, shadow-dom

I'm using Chrome dev tools to check my css selectors when writing E2E-Tests using Playwright (or Puppeteer).

To verify a selector is valid and can be found I use the cmd+f search-bar in Elements-Tab in DevTools like this:

[image: found selector outside shadow-root]

But how can I find selectors inside shadow-root?

[image: no match]

Just to make clear: This selector can be found via code. I just can't find it in the DevTools

Comment: Devtools can't do that anymore. In the past it was possible but now Chrome has removed shadow-piercing combinators. You can suggest them to try to make the search work in UI at least, maybe they'll find a way.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done in two stages using shadowRoot.

First assign element with shadow dom to a constant, then use querySelector to target element(s) inside shadow.

```
const element = document.querySelector('wc-article-editor'):
element.shadowRoot.querySelector('.myclass');
```

Comment: Ok, with this I can at least check the selector in the console - but not my preferred way in the Elements-Tab of the dev-tools. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I guess that colon is supposed to be a semicolon ;)